# Change holo spinner text colour

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner, android-styles

I have a spinner in a Holo theme dialog and am trying to change the text colour because it is very hard to read:

[image: dialog spinner text colour]

I have looked at android styles.xml, as well as many other answers, and believe that I am setting the custom style correctly; but it's just not getting picked up.

This is an extract from the dialog layout file where the spinner lives:

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spn_Type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:entries="@array/dose_type_options"
        style="@style/DialogSpinner" />
```

And these are the relevant entries in styles.xml in the values-v14 folder:

```
<style name="DialogSpinner" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Spinner">
        <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/MySpinnerItem</item>
</style>

<style name="MySpinnerItem" parent="android:Widget.Holo.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/MyTextAppearanceSpinnerItem</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTextAppearanceSpinnerItem" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFF</item>
</style>
```

The dialog itself is forced to the Holo dark theme by using:

```
<style name="FibroDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">

</style>
```

Can anyone identify why the spinner text isn't white?

I have looked at other solutions, which suggest changing the colour in code, but this app supports 2.3.* upwards, so for those non-holo versions black text is fine, hence trying to do it by styles.

Thanks

**Updated using answer from Woda below**

The text colour of the initial value of the spinner is now white, which goes a long way to highlighting that there is a spinner there for the user:

[image: dialog spinner text colour 2]

But the text colour of the selectable items is still black. I guess it's not a massive deal, at least the existence of the spinner has been affirmed by getting the initial text changed to white. But I would be interested to know why the items are still black, and how to change them to white.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried to accept the SpinnerItemStyle to your Theme? So all Spinners in your App would've the same style. I'm using it like this and it works:

theme.xml:

```
<style name="exampleTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem_example</item>
    ...
</style>
```

style.xml:

```
<style name="SpinnerItem_example" parent="android:TextAppearance.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>
```

**Update:**
Taking a deeper look into the styles.xml brought me this:

```
<style name="Widget.DropDownItem.Spinner">
        <item name="android:checkMark">?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.DropDownItem">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Widget.DropDownItem</item>
        <item name="android:paddingStart">@dimen/dropdownitem_text_padding_left</item>
        <item name="android:paddingEnd">@dimen/dropdownitem_text_padding_right</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
</style>
```

So you probably need to customize the Widget.DropDownItem and accept it in your theme.

```
...
<item name="dropDownItemStyle">@android:style/Widget.DropDownItem</item>
...
```

For customizing my application the following two links helped me a lot to understand the structure of the different views. These two files are part of the android source code. May be it helps you too.

- [themes.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml)
- [styles.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml)

Comment: Thanks, Woda. That's done enough for me for now. See my updates above for what happened.

Comment: I updated my answer above. Unfortunatley I don't have the time to check exactly solves your problem.

Comment: No, that didn't seem to work. But thanks for the initial answer.

Comment: I'm new to Android, so i need to know Where to put theme.xml and style.xml files? and how to apply them??

Answer (score 4):

I fixed it by calling

```
mArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewTheme(mActivity.getTheme());
```

Hope this helps someone ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the internal TextView in code without changing any styles. This is how I handled enabling and disabling Spinners

The .getSelectedView() did not work for me. So I tricked the Spinner to "show" being disabled.

You will need to define your own colors for the "disabled" look.

For Example:

```
R.color.blue_text //means enabled
R.color.gray_text //means disabled
```

So to disable my spinner:

```
((TextView)mySpinner.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gray_text));
mySpinner.setEnabled(false);
mySpinner.setFocusable(false);
```

To enable my spinner:

```
((TextView)mySpinner.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_text));
mySpinner.setEnabled(true);
mySpinner.setFocusable(true);
```

The getChildAt(0) function allows you to access the first item in the spinner, which is what you show on the screen as a TextView.

You don't need to change styles or modify any XML. Just do this in your code, even within event methods, you should be fine.