# Change the textColor to black for all spinner elements in Holo.LIght

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-styles

I'm using the theme Holo.Light  and I want to change the color text of the selected element when the spinner is not opened. 
I mean, when I select the spinner and it displays the list, the color text of the elements is correct (black), but when I select one and the list is closed, it is displayed in the box using white color and I want to change it to black as the others.

If I set this in the onItemSelected listener it works:

```
 ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```

But, Is it possible to solve my problem just using xml? Why if I set in all places the black color for the text it still uses white color?

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/SpinnerTheme</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItemStyle</item>

</style>


<style name="SpinnerDropDownStyle" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.TextView.SpinnerItem">
     <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
     <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_extra_large</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">60dp</item>

</style>


<style name="SpinnerTheme" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/dark_gray</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_medium</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerMode">dialog</item>
</style>


<style name="SpinnerItemStyle" parent="android:TextAppearance.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/dark_gray</item>
</style>
```

**My custom  row layout :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/spinnerText"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
/>
```

**My custom dropdown row layout :**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/spinnerText"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
style="@style/SpinnerDropDownStyle"/>
```

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16638901/4385913)

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't work